# Comparison of point-biserial and linear correlation coefficients

Tags: correlation, binary-data, pearson-r

I have a continuous variable X that is associated with a continuous outcome Y and a dichotomous outcome Z.

If I calculate Pearson's $r$ between X and Y, and the point-biserial coefficient $r_{pb}$ between X and Z, and find that the coefficient between X and Y is much higher than the coefficient between X and Z, can I say "The association between X and Y is much stronger than the association between X and Z," or are those coefficients non-comparable?

If not, is there a reasonable way to compare the associations for the two pairs (X and Y, and X and Z)?